# this inside function

Tags: javascript, function, this

My question is:

```
function Foo()
{
   this.foo = "bar"; // <- What is "this" here?
}
```

From what I can tell it depends on how `Foo` is used, i.e. as a constructor or as a function. What can `this` be in different circumstances?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the object the function belongs to, or the `window` object if the function belongs to no object.

It's used in OOP code, to refer to the class/object the function belongs to
For example:

```
function foo() {
    this.value = 'Hello, world';

    this.bar = function() {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

var inst = new foo();
inst.bar();
```

This alerts: `Hello, world`

You can manipulate which object `this` refers to by using the `apply()` or `call()` functions. *(A very very handy feature at times)*

```
var bar1 = new function() {
    this.value = '#1';
}
var bar2 = new function() {
    this.value = '#2';
}

function foo() {
    alert(this.value);
}

foo.call(bar1); // Output: #1
foo.apply(bar2, []); // Output: #2
```

Comment: I am curious too. is there something wrong with his explanation?

Comment: The answer by @Danben puts the emphasis on using the new keyword, which creates a new object (the javascript prototype way). Without it, no new object is created and the function is "interned" (if I can say so) to the object it belongs, or the global window object if in browser.

Comment: If you have class Foo { function Bar() { console.log(this); } }, using "this" in new Foo().Bar() should result in Foo, not Bar. But if you use "var x = new Foo.Bar()", then new Foo.Bar object will be created and "this" will refer to Bar.

Answer (score 28):

Read what Douglas Crockford has to say on the matter, to quote him from [A Survey of the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html):

> A function is an object. It can contain members just as other objects. This allows a function to contain its own data tables. It also allows an object to act as a class, containing a constructor and a set of related methods.
>
> A function can be a member of an object. When a function is a member of an object, it is called a method. There is a special variable, called this that is set to the object when a method of the object is called.
>
> For example, in the expression foo.bar(), the this variable is set to the object foo as a sort of extra argument for the function bar. The function bar can then refer to this to access the object of interest.
>
> In a deeper expression like do.re.mi.fa(), the this variable is set to the object do.re.mi, not to the object do. In a simple function call, this is set to the Global Object (aka window), which is not very useful. The correct behavior should have been to preserve the current value of this, particularly when calling inner functions.

Also 'this' can change depending on how your function is invoked, read on [apply function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply) and [call function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%3aGlobal_Objects%3aFunction%3acall).

I would recommend that you spend time learning form one of JavaScript's greatest minds in his (free) presentations, linked from [here](http://www.metafilter.com/61049/Douglas-Crockford-Teaches-JavaScript).

Comment: Links on the Crawford page to Yahoo URLs are all broken. Most likely alternative I could find is the 4-video sequence starting at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M

Answer (score 10):

In JavaScript, the convention (and this is only a convention) is that any function that begins with a capital letter is to be used as a constructor.  Then, one would call

`var foo = new Foo()` and `this` would refer to the newly created object that is about to be referenced by `foo`.

Of course, there is nothing stopping you from calling `Foo()` on its own, in which case `this` would then refer to the object from which the function was called.  To avoid confusion, that is not recommended.

Comment: It's great that you clarify the usage of the new keyword, because almost no casual users are familiar with how javascript prototype-based objects work, and it causes too much confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Its depends on how that function is used, there are two basic types in which we can use functions

1. Function
2. Function as an Object, by using new keyword

will see one by one

1.Function

```
var example = function () {
  console.log(this);
};

example();

Output : window
```

Here 'this' keyword points to window object.

By default, this should always be the window Object, which refers to the root - the global scope. So when we console.log(this); from our function, as it’s invoked by the window (simply just called), we should expect the this value to be our window Object:

2.Function as an Object

```
var example = function () {
  console.log(this);
};

var obj = new example();

Output : example {}
```

Here 'this' keyword points to newly created example object.

Answer (score 3):

In NodeJS there is some interesting behaviour:

```js
function foo() {
    this.name = 'bar' // <- What is "this" here?
}

foo() // <- TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

But using an arrow function:

```js
const bar = () => {
    this.name = 'foo'
    console.log(this)
}

bar() // <- { name: 'foo' }
```

I was always under the impression that a traditional function literal had its own context but not arrow functions, this seems to contradict my understanding.

Given this behaviour the code by the OP would not work...

Comment: it's because scope of a regular function and arrow function is different. Arrow functions have it's closure context while other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript everything is object even functions. When you say `this.foo` in following code

```
function Foo()
{
   this.foo = "bar"; // <- What is "this" here?
}
```

`foo` becomes member variable of `Foo` object

Comment: I may have function MyClass () { function MyMethod () { console.log(this); } } and that log call should record MyClass, not MyMethod. Notice that both MyClass and MyMethod are functions, but no one would call new MyClass.MyMethod() if the design was not deliberately meant so.

Comment: To expand Luka's example: if Foo() is not a member function of some custom object, it becomes a member function of the global object (`window` if executed in web browser) in which case `this` will still point to the `window` and then `foo` will become member variable of `window`.

Comment: 'window' scope is the important point here. Very nice, @JustAMartin.