# PHP $$ conterpart in JS

Tags: javascript, php, var

Is there any counterpart for the following statement in JS:

```
foreach (['a'=>1,'b'=>2] as $k->$v) {
        $$k=$v;
}
```

You may suggest the following code. But it declares the variables in the global scope.

```
for(k in {a: 1, b: 2})
  {
      window[k]=this[k];
  }
```

Comment: What scope do you want it in?  Your PHP could be in function, file, or global scope depending upon where you are, so it's not clear to me what JS equivalent you want.

Comment: Is this absolutely necessary? Usually it is not, can and should be avoided

Comment: @bishop It's in function scope.

Comment: Isn't `this` the right thing to use in [function scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963357/this-inside-function)? `this[k] = v`

Comment: Well, the only way to emulate variable variables in Javascript is with a context object (eg, `this` or `window`), but functions generally are not objects so "this" might not refer to the particular object.  You might be able to use the prototype `Function[k]`, but that sounds dangerous.  I would put this in some kind of context object and pass that around.

Comment: shouldn't that be window[k] ?

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Variable variables are a horrible even  in a language like PHP. Please don't try to bring them to javascript.

Comment: @grebneke Yes, It should. Thanks.

Comment: @AxelAmthor Yes, It should. Thanks.

Comment: @JanDvorak Look harder...

Answer (score 0):

You should not use variable variables in PHP anyway. Use arrays instead. `window[k]` is an example of using an array instead (well, an object, but close enough).

As you discovered, there is no way to use local scope variables in JavaScript, so do yourself a favour, use objects ;)

Comment: Please help community moderation by voting to close as a duplicate rather than posting your own answer. Also, I'm not sure this really _is_ an answer.