# Why is Javascript object reference not updated?

Tags: javascript, reference, this

I'm creating a bunch of objects and I want to use some of the objects in others, so I'm passing them in so I can update them later. I'd expect to hold a reference to each object, but if I pass an object before it's created, it stays undefined even after I create it. Here's the code:

```
this.screen = new BatchScreen(screenList);
this.fieldData = new FieldData(this.screen, this.nutrientData);
this.nutrientData = new NutrientData(this.screen, this.fieldData);

function FieldData(screen, nutrientData)
{
    this.nutrientData = nutrientData;
}
```

this.fieldData.nutrientData is "undefined", which I don't understand as I thought this.fieldData holds a reference to this.nutrientData, which I create after it's assigned in this.fieldData.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this inside function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963357/this-inside-function)

Comment: How do you "*pass an object before it's created*"?

Comment: @RobG - obviously you just use jQuery and delegate the dropping to a parent object.

Comment: @adeneo—ah, must be part of the new crystal ball plugin.

Comment: @RobG - I was being lazy, I could set this.nutrientData = null first, which would work in any other language, but to Javascript it's the same in this context.

Comment: Here is a simpler version of your problem: `var foo = 42; bar = foo; foo = 21;`. You expected `bar` to be 21, but that's not how JavaScript works. The type of value doesn't matter.

Comment: @Felix Kling - sorry, no. If I set this.screen = null, this.fieldData.screen will also be null. This is a different problem which is well explained by the answer I accepted.

Comment: I reduced the problem to the simplest case that demonstrates that JS is not *pass-by-reference*. If you like it a bit more specific to your case: `var nutrientData = this.nutrientData; this.fieldData = {nutrientData: nutrientData}; this.nutrientData = 42;`. You expected that setting `this.nutationData` will also change `nutationData` and through that `this.fieldData.nutationData`. I just removed the layers of indirection to make the problem easier to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short: you are not passing references.

Long: the evaluation strategy in JS is something called [Call by sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). It also is explained as "references passed by values".

What it means in details is that - in your

```
this.fieldData = new FieldData(this.screen, this.nutrientData);
```

statement the `this.screen` holds a reference, so it's passed by value. And the `this.nutrientData` holds nothing - so `undefined` is passed.

Then when you run

```
this.nutrientData = new NutrientData(this.screen, this.fieldData);
```

statement the `this.nutrientData` is being defined as a reference to a new object. But it's too late - we have already passed the `undefined` in the `FieldData` constructor.

So the best way to understand it - is to always think that the data is always passed by values, but sometimes those values keep references.

For your code to work as you expect the `self.nutrientData` and others must be pointers, which JS does not support in any way.

**The solution**:

if you have 2 mutially dependent objects then you cannot have both in their own constructors. One of them just have to expose additional setter and accept the dependency through it.

Comment: Thanks - that explains why it doesn't work. Still looking for a fix, is it even possible or do I have to pass "this" (the parent), which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but a possible solution. You really need a [*getter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) but support isn't sufficiently widespread. If you have interdependent properties, you can implement a getter for one (or perhaps both for consistency) so you have:

```
this.screen = new BatchScreen(screenList);

// Don't bother passing this.nutrientData since you know it's not defined yet,
// pass in the object that you want the nutrientData property of
this.fieldData = new FieldData(this.screen, this);
this.nutrientData = new NutrientData(this.screen, this.fieldData);

// In here, use a function to return the property so its read when called, 
// not when defined
function FieldData(screen, obj) {
    this.getNutrientData = function () {return obj.nutrientData};
}
```

Then instead of:

```
var foo = someInstance.fieldData.nutrientData;
```

use:

```
var foo = someInstance.fieldData.getNutrientData();
```

But there seems to be a circular relationship between *fieldData* and *nutrientData*.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `this.nutrientData` in the second line, is not being passed as a reference, since no reference to an object exists (at that point there is no this.nutrientData, so you are literally passing `undefined`).

I'd guess you are also having scope issues with `this`;

Try this (no pun intended):

```
var self = this;
this.screen = new BatchScreen(screenList);
this.fieldData = new FieldData(self.screen, new NutrientData(self.screen, self.fieldData));
// assumes that the nutrientData property exists from the object passed into FieldData
this.nutrientData = this.fieldData.nutrientData;
function FieldData(screen, nutrientData)
{
    this.nutrientData = nutrientData;
}
```