# Cannot access variable in object from outside

Tags: javascript

I didn't succeed in accessing the variable playing from outside the object Pong:

```
Pong = {
// some other objects
initialize: function (runner, cfg) {
    Game.loadImages(Pong.Images, function (images) {
        this.cfg = cfg;
        this.runner = runner;
        this.width = runner.width;
        this.height = runner.height;
        this.images = images;
        this.playing = false; // variable is defined here
        this.scores = [0, 0];
        this.menu = Object.construct(Pong.Menu, this);
        this.court = Object.construct(Pong.Court, this);
        this.leftPaddle = Object.construct(Pong.Paddle, this);
        this.rightPaddle = Object.construct(Pong.Paddle, this, true);
        this.ball = Object.construct(Pong.Ball, this);
        this.sounds = Object.construct(Pong.Sounds, this);
        this.runner.start();
    } .bind(this));
}, 
// some more functions 
isPlaying: function () { // I added this function to enable for access
    return this.playing; // here playing is undefined
},

start: function (numPlayers) {
    if (!this.playing) { // here playing is defined
        this.scores = [0, 0];
        this.playing = true;
        this.leftPaddle.setAuto(numPlayers < 1, this.level(0));
        this.rightPaddle.setAuto(numPlayers < 2, this.level(1));
        this.ball.reset();
        this.runner.hideCursor();
    }
},
// more objects and functions
```

This is a pingpong game. The complete page is this:
http://ulrichbangert.de/div/webdesign/javascript/pong.html I cannot understand why this variable can be accessed in start and not in isPlaying.
Why is this and what code do I have to use to access this variable? To enable for debugging I added calling isPlaying in the onclick event.

Comment: put together a minimal version of your page with JsFiddle, so we can easily help you

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the classic problems with javascript, `this` changing "unexpectedly".

Inside of that callback, `this` points to something else, not your object. One of solutions is to trap object reference in a closure.

```
initialize: function (runner, cfg) {
  var that = this; // <= "that" won't change.
  Game.loadImages(Pong.Images, function (images) {
      that.cfg = cfg;
      that.playing = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but it doesn't meet my question: My problem is not that the variable is changing unexpectedly. Instead this is intended. My problem is that I do not know how to access that variable from outside the object Pong. What is "this" in function initialize (It's not Pong and it's not Game) and how can it be accessed from outsinde Pong?

Comment: `this` in `initialize` is a Pong. `this` in callback of `loadImages` is something else (I'd guess, the callback itself).

Comment: Quote from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963357/this-inside-function
"The this keyword refers to the object the function belongs to, or the window object if the function belongs to no object." confirms your statement: "this in initialize is a Pong". Unfortunately the debugger tells a different thing: Pong.playing is undefined.

Comment: @Sempervivum: "Pong.playing is undefined" - of course. It's __a__ Pong, not __the__ Pong.