# Javascript Function.prototype.call() pass primitive value

Tags: javascript, this, call, primitive

I want to pass an index-variable as `this` to a function I call with `function.call()`.

```
var fun = function() {
    console.log( this );
}

fun.call( 1 );
// -> Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}
```

So obviously the primitive integer `1` is not passed as primitive to the called function.
According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Parameters) for Function.prototype.call() "[...] primitive values will be converted to objects."

Is there a way to pass it to `fun()` as primitive integer?

Comment: This reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What do you hope to achieve by doing this?

Comment: if javascript behaviour is to convert primitives to objects, then I can't see how you can avoid it, short of writing your own javascript engine ... however, that statement implies this behaviour is in strict mode only

Comment: Why do you care if `this` is a primitive? If that's what you want, why not pass it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

In the above example `1` is passed as an `integer` param but internally it is a object of `number` type to the `fun` function.  So in order to access the value of `integer` from `this`. Use `this.valueOf()`.  I think this helps you!

```js
var x = 12;

function fun() {
  console.log(this.valueOf());
}

fun.call(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well what you want is never possible as per the definition of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963357/this-inside-function) inside a function. Yes there can be way arounds as given in the other answers for your implementation.