# javascript typeof(this) in function output object not FUNCTION type

Tags: javascript

the javascript code like below:

```
function aa(){
    console.log(typeof(this))
}

console.log(typeof(aa))

aa()
```

the output is **function** and **object** after running this code.

so why the code output difference type?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `aa` and `this` refer to different values, one of them not being a function. If you want to learn how `this` works I recommend to read https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md . Also note that `typeof` is not a function but an operator, so you should just be writing `typeof aa`.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963357/this-inside-function

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what about run it in node.js? which is 'this' refer to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the execution of a function that has been called without passing a context `this` is bound the the global `window` object of the browser.

`this` is never the function object itself, unless you pass that explicitly with `call` or `apply`.

The output of

```
function f(){console.log(typeof this);}
f.call(f);
```

will be `function`.

Comment: thanks, but I run my code with node.js, no window in it. Moreover, I think FUNCTION also a type in javascript?