# Why my function does not get value of 'this.arg'

Tags: javascript, function, this

I wrote the  below code but as expected it should give value as 4 but it is giving undefined. I am not able to understand why?

```
function outputInteger (a) {
 console.log(this.a);
}
outputInteger(4);
```

expected result : 4
given result : undefined

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963357/this-inside-function)

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to your parameter `a` just by it's name:

```
function outputInteger (a) {
 console.log(a);
}
outputInteger(4);
```

Comment: `this` is unrelated to the fact that functions are objects. The problem is rather that `this` inside a "normal" function call is meaningless. In strict mode the OP's code would actually throw an error.

Comment: True, I'll remove that.