# How to get $scope or $element in an onblur event and run a function in an onblur event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

I added an `onblur` event to all input fields, and I want to get the `$scope` and `$element` when the `onblur` event runs. But when I use `this.$element` to get the element, I get `undefined`.

When I log only this, I get the input tag.
How can I get the `$scope` and `$element` on an `onblur` event?

Code:

```
constructor($document, $element, $scope) {
   this.$document = $document;
   this.$element = $element;
   this.$scope= $scope;
}

FunCall() {
  const formElements = this.$element[0].querySelectorAll('input');
  const watchElement = angular.element(formElements[0]);
  console.log(this);

  watchElement[0].onblur = function() {
    console.log(this); // html input element
    console.log(this.$scope); // undefined
    console.log(this.$element); // undefined
  };
}
```

On the first log I get the correct this, which is the controller. On the second log, inside the `onblur` event I get the HTML element and get `undefined` for the `$scope` and `$element`. How can I get the controller, like the first one inside the `onblur` event?

And I want to run a function inside the `onblur` event, but this didn't work:

```
watchElement[0].onblur = function() {
    this.runSecondFunction();
};

runSecondFunction() {
 console.log('test 2nd function');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function()` in javascript is also a constructor. This why, you can create an object by `new`. For example:

```js
function ImAFunctionButCanBeConstructor() {
  this.foo = 'bar';
  this.print = function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}

const myObj = new ImAFunctionButCanBeConstructor();
myObj.print();
```

In a case of an event handler `this` is referring to the [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#In_an_inline_event_handler).

In order to avoid this (only if you don't need that reference), you can use an arrow function instead of regular function so `this` [will refer to the enclosing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions), which is the instance of the class.

```js
class MyComp {
  constructor($document, $element, $scope) {
    this.$document = $document;
    this.$element = $element;
    this.$scope = $scope;

    this.FunCall();
  }

  FunCall() {
    const formElements = this.$element[0].querySelectorAll("input");
    const watchElement = angular.element(formElements[0]);
    //console.log(this);

    watchElement[0].onblur = () => {
      //console.log(this);
      //console.log(this.$scope);
      console.log(this.$element);
    };
  }
}

angular.module("app", []).component("myComp", {
  controller: MyComp,
  template: `
      <input type="text" placeholder="watch me blur" />
    `
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" ng-app="app">
  <my-comp></my-comp>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-moore-kohg8?file=/src/index.js

Just has to mention **There are more ways to do the same**.

---

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1963370/863110