# this/apply/call/bind in JavaScript, invisible parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript problem that involves hiding a parameter to demonstrate how `this` works.

The problem involves searching for an array, `[1,2]`, in a search space which is a multidimensional array, e.g `[[2,3], [3,4]]`. However, the search space is passed in as part of `this` value to the function.

Function definition:

```
function contains(cell) {}
```

How do I access the search space passed in as `this` to the function? The accompanying testcase uses `bind()` to pass in the search space e.g

```
contains.bind([[2,3], [3,4]])
```

Here is the attempt at completing the function:

```
function contains(cell){
   let found = false;
   [x, y] = cell;

   // How do I access searchSpace passed in through `this`?
   searchSpace.forEach((element) => {
     [j, k] = element;
     // match first occurrence in array
     if (x === j && y === k){
        found = true;
     }
   });
   return found;
}
```

How do I invoke the function:

```
// contains(cell)
contains([1,2])
```

Comment: I think it should be `contains.bind(this, [[2,3], [3,4]])` (if you just want to bind the context to the function, without calling it yet), or `contains.call(this, [[2,3], [3,4]])` if you want to pass the context and call the function immediately. But if you do `contains().bind()` you are _executing_ `contains()`, and then, applying `.bind()` to whatever it returns (`found`, which is a boolean). A boolean has no `.bind()` method.

Comment: I need to substitute the line `searchSpace.forEach(` for `this.forEach(` because after calling bind(), I think `this` should contain the object, `[[2,3], [3,4]]` but in my case, it contains the global window object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind `[[2,3], [3,4]]` as `this` to the `contains` function it would be `contains.bind([[2,3], [3,4]])` and not `contains().bind([[2,3], [3,4]])`.

And `bind` does not change the function on which it is called directly so `contains.bind([[2,3], [3,4]])` alone and then calling `contains` won't do anything.

`bind` returns a new function, and that function then calls `contains` with the given value as `this`.

> How do I access the search space passed in as `this` to the function?

By using `this` in the function.

```js
function contains(cell) {
   console.dir(this)
   console.dir(cell)
}

const containsWithBind = contains.bind([[2,3], [3,4]])

containsWithBind([1,2])
```

How your code attempt should look like:

```js
function contains(cell){
   let found = false;
   [x, y] = cell;

   // How do I access searchSpace passed in through `this`?
   this.forEach((element) => {
     [j, k] = element;
     // match first occurrence in array
     if (x === j && y === k){
        found = true;
     }
   });
   return found;
}

const containtsWithBind =  contains.bind([[2,3], [3,4]])

// contains(cell)
console.log(containtsWithBind([1,2]))
console.log(containtsWithBind([2,3]))
```

Comment: Do you mean the line, `searchSpace.forEach(` should be substituted for `this.forEach(` because after calling `bind()`, `this` now contains the object, `[[2,3], [3,4]]`?

Doing that doesn't work. `this` contains the global window object.

Comment: @Brayoni `Do you mean the line, searchSpace.forEach( should be substituted for this.forEach(` yes. `Doing that doesn't work. this contains the global window object.` you then didn't follow my instructions (`bind` does not change the function on which it is called, it returns a new function for which the given value is bound as `this`). In addition to the original simplified version, I now added your code with `searchSpace` replaced by `this` into my answer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass that value as a variable to the `contains` function. `this` refers to something different in and out of the function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963357/this-inside-function) for more context).

The easiest approach would be:

```
function contains(cell, searchSpace){
   let found = false;
   [x, y] = cell;

   // How do I access searchSpace passed in through `this`?
   searchSpace.forEach((element) => {
     [j, k] = element;
     // match first occurrence in array
     if (x === j && y === k){
        found = true;
     }
   });
   return found;
}

contains([1,2], this.searchSpace);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I'm looking for. Doing `this.searchSpace` is not necessary as the function signature already accepts two parameters one being the `searchSpace` in your example. I'd like to access the `searchSpace` without passing it in the function as a parameter, so the function remains to be `function contains(cell){}`